# How to make \begin{align} looks like \begin{eqnarray}

Tags: align, eqnarray

I trying to align a programming model using eqnarray but the command \tag do not work with it, I could use align instead but the alignment is right for the first column and left for the second column.

So what I want to do is use the eqnarray alignment (which is right for the first column and centered for the second column) with align.

This is how both commands look like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! No `=`sign (or `<` or …) between the two ‘columns’?

Comment: Nope, that's why I don't want the right-left alignment

Comment: Centred w.r.t. what? And should the first column be aligned?

Comment: I added a picture so you can see what the problem is

Comment: the way you are using `eqnarray

Comment: the way you are using `eqnarray` is not the way it was designed to be used. (and that is done badly, which is why `align` is recommended as an alternative.)  but since you have a requirement to center what is in the "second" column, i'd say continue to use `eqnarray`.

Comment: the problem with eqnarray is that it does not allow me to use the command \tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `\mathmakebox` from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% loads `amsmath'
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Max}{Max}
\begin{document}
A solution with \verb|\mathmakebox|:
\begin{alignat}{2}
           \Max_t & \quad & F(t) = at, \\
\text{subject to} &       & \mathmakebox[\widthof{$F(t) = at,$}][c]{t \le b,} \\
                  &       & \mathmakebox[\widthof{$F(t) = at,$}][c]{t \ge 0.}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image: makebox]

Comment: (+1) I had completely forgotten this command (much more recent than eqparbox)!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two  possibilities with `alignat` and  `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  \max_t & &\quad & \eqmathbox{F(t) = at}\\
 \text{subject to}& &
 & \eqmathbox{\begin{gathered}[t]
 t\le b, \\t\ge 0.
 \end{gathered}}
\end{alignat}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  \max_t & &\quad & \eqmathbox{F(t) = at}\\
 \text{subject to}& &
 & \eqmathbox{t \le b,} \\
  & & & \eqmathbox{t \ge 0.}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is the mathtools package only needed with gathered?

Comment: It is a very useful extension of  `amsmath` (which would be enough for this code), deeply recommended. B.t.w., `eqnarray` shouldn't be used any more, as it leads to bad spacings.